# Difference in SQLite query times

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

When I run query from within C and in "DB Brownser for SQLite" I get wildly different query times. Here is an example:

```
sqlite3 *db;
int rc = sqlite3_open("New.db", &db);

// Execute
clock_t t0 = clock();
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT * FROM Sales1M s1 join Sales1M s2 on (s1.id=s2.id) GROUP BY s1.territory_id, s2.code", -1, &stmt, NULL);
clock_t t1 = clock();

// Fetch
int rownum=1;
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    // printf("Row: %d | Code: %s | TerritoryID: %s\n", rownum, sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3));
    rownum++;
}
clock_t t2 = clock();

printf("ExecuteSQL: %.6f | FetchSQL: %.6f\n" ...<some other info>);
```

> ExecuteSQL: 0.000451 | FetchSQL: 6.510507 (520 rows returned)

And in the client (DB Browser) that exact same query takes 35s. Here's a visual comparison:

[image]

I've run the query multiple times in each and every time it takes about the same time. What accounts for the drastic difference in these two identical queries?

Comment: Stating the obvious, it seems your app has a lot of overhead to it.

Comment: Does db browser measure just the time spent executing the query, or include time spent rendering and displaying the results too? If as seems likely it's the latter case, the two aren't really equivalent.... Comparing the time to cut down a tree vs the time to turn it into lumber on top of that.

Comment: @Shawn I would assume it's both, but the results are only 520 rows, and it takes almost just as long if I reduce it to two rows or so, so I don't think (though I may be wrong?) the display itself should take too long with this particular query.

Comment: @Shared  This just probably indicates that the extra time spent in DB Browser is not proportional to the number of rows because the other UI preparation, analysis of the SQL prior to execution, preparing data structures for retrieval of data, etc., are not dependent upon number of rows.  Shawn's point is simply that DB Browser is doing many more things than simply retrieving the raw data.  Test a different sqlite manager/browser software and/or a different host language for comparison.